# Combine models and send to template

Tags: django

I want multiple data to be sent from two different model to a template

```
class UserListView(generic.ListView):
        model = UserProfile
        template_name = 'users/users.html'
        context_object_name = 'users'

class UserListView(generic.ListView):
        model = User
        template_name = 'users/users.html'
        context_object_name = 'users'
```

Comment: You can't have two different views called the same thing. But you need to show your models; I can guess how UserProfile is related to User but it would be clearer if you showed it explicitly.

Comment: class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)                                      User  Model is DjangoAdminAuthModel

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access **UserProfile** data in **User**(or vice versa) as they have [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) relation. But using same template will probably be bad idea (for two seperate views). Lets say if you keep only `UserListView`, then you can try like this in  `users/users.html`:

```
{% for obj in objects %}
    {{ obj.userprofile }}    
{% endfor %}
```